# Is there an easy way to have the copyright notice automatically added by android studio?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, copyright-display

I have just started learning android and using the Android Studio by IntelliJ, so please bear with me if this is a very stupid question to ask.

Is there a way to have copyright notice text automatically added to source code files, by android studio IDE?

I have eclipse setup to automatically add copyright notice text at the top of my source code file, whenever it is created. 
So, I am expecting something similar for android studio as well.

Please note: I know that I can easily do it by write a script that can add a license text, so please don't suggest that as an answer.

Thanks for reading this question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Preferences --> Copyright --> Copyright Profiles, create a profile, and replace the default text with your own custom copyright notice. You can then format it in **Formatting** tab.

Example: [image]

Then in Copyright tab, select your profile (in my example **"test"**), and copyright text will be added to new source files you create.

[image]

To add/update the copyright to existing project files, select Code -> Update Copyright from the menu bar and select the scope of files that should be updated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It was very helpful.

Just to share what I additionally found:
I also found that once I updated the copyright profile, the "Update Copyright" option in "Code" menu got enabled and I could have the copyright notice added to all existing files of my project.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `preference` menu and search for `copyright` using the search-box.

There are a bunch of options to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create copyright profile.

1. Go to Settings > Copyright > Copyright profiles
2. Go to Settings > Copyright and change the default copyright to the new one you created.

You can find more information here https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/copyright-profiles.html